# connecting android app with database at server

Tags: android

I'm a beginner in android and I'm making an app in which I want to make a login screen. I want the log in credentials work through a database that is kept at [byethost.com](http://www.byethost.com) *(free website host)*.

I follow the example on [androidhive.info](http://androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/). When I check from the postman the web service is called. But when I'm logging in nothing happens and similarly while registering - nothing gets updated in the database.

Here is my log cat.

[image]

Comment: 1. Did you use post or get? I think you should use post instead get

Comment: You've exception with parsing html data as json. Make sure You're responding with json data.

Answer (score 1):

As shown in `logcat`

> Value of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

You are receiving the response from server in form of `String`. And you are treating it as a `JSONObject`. Thats not possible.

Comment: No . It's not the real reason.

Comment: when i m clicking on the login button then the message comes...Json error : value <html><body>script of type java.lang.String cannot be comverted to JsonObject